# Array that persists across executions of PHP scripts

Tags: php, arrays, persistence

I am working on IR for local language. Indexing the document and storing in file is done by Java. Then a PHP script reads the index file from storage and convert back to term-document matrix. Reading and converting to matrix is expensive in terms of computation and it takes time. As a result, I want to read it once and store in matrix and reuse it (stay in memory across requests). What are the ways to do this? Is there a work around for this?

Comment: `sessions`, `database`, `xml` - all possible

Comment: Sessions/xml are stored in a file, right? So, how can that solve the problem of reading it again and again for each user query?

Answer (score 1):

Redis is an in memory database and might be the ideal solution. It works with a ton of different languages including php and java so there should be no issues.

Comment: I will check that. If it is in memory database, that seems a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If reading AND converting is heavy computationally, then possibly convert once and save as a single xml file.
Reading an xml file back into memory with php should be fast enough (depending on the amount-of-data/file-size and drive read speed).
If it is too much data to write & read, them memory database should is a great solution - just watch the total memory used. If it gets more than total php memory allowed, then it's going to cache to the harddrive anyway.
Otherwise it is a good solution, just a little more work (and complex) to set up.
I would test xml file as an easy first option, especially if you have file caching enabled in the httpd.

Comment: It is not possible to determine the index file size since the IR system is expected to run on a website and the number of files on a website grows over time. However, I haven't considered XML file previously and I will see if XML could be read at an acceptable speed.